# Why does this for loop repeat?

Tags: python

I am currently struggling with this concept.

Sorry I was a bit unclear to begin with. My output is to print each alphabet from the words in the orig_list. But in my program instead of stopping at the last alphabet in the last word of the orig_list which is (s) it starts again from the beginning

```
alphabet  = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'    
orig_list = [ "bat", "act", "cat", "rat", "abs" ]

for i in alphabet:
    for j in orig_list:
        for l in j:
            print(l)
```

I will provide the output below. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
b
a
t
a
c
t
c
a
t
r
a
t
a
b
s
b
a
t
a
c
t
c
a
t
r
a
t
a
b
s
..... and so on
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me, what is your desired output ?

Comment: Try removing the `for i in alphabet:` line, it doesn't seem to be relevant to your desired output and is the cause of the "repeating"

Comment: Your program does what you tell it to do. It prints 26 times all letters of all  words in orig_list - as in: for each letter in the alphabet it does each word in the list and prints each if its letters

Comment: For a simpler example, use `alphabet = 'ab'; orig_list = ["xy"]`

Comment: BTW note that "alphabets" is dialectal in Indian English. Everyone else calls them "letters".

Answer (score 1):

You're currently doing the following:

```
For every letter in the alphabet:
  For every string in the list:
    For every letter in the string:
      print the letter
```

So you're printing every letter in every list item once per letter of the alphabet. Remove the first line of the loop if you only want to print the strings in the list once.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know any resources to learn these small nuances? I have tried doing a lot of tutorials and videos online but rather than conceptual they just teach me how to do it. While at school I am being tested on smaller things. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: @coolios You really just need to go through your own code step by step, perhaps with pen and paper. Try to interpret your code the way the computer will and write down what happens in each step.